# Add reputation at post time to PostHistory records in the data dump

Tags: feature-request, reputation, data-explorer, data-dump

One of the weaknesses of the data dump is that it is not possible to determine a user's reputation at a particular point in time.  This is "by-design" and perfectly okay.  However, there are a number of reasons why we might want to determine the reputation of a user at the time they created or edited a specific post. Can this information be added to the PostHistory records in the data explorer?

The impetus for this is that I've noticed people spending more time trying to find ways to limit or track down low quality posts, which often originate from users with very low rep.  Since even a few days later a user's rep may have changed significantly relative to a small threshold like 10 or 50, there's a need to know what an individual's rep was at the time a post was created/edited.

I fully expect this to be declined, as I doubt this information is stored in an easy way in the live database right now, but hey — it doesn't hurt to ask :)

Comment: This would be very useful for the Machine Learning Contest - http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/08/stack-exchange-machine-learning-contest/

Comment: I think it is a very nice idea, all the stats we want to generate depending on the user activity/treatment by reputation, are significantly worsened and complicated, because there is no easy way to even *estimate* the rep at the given time.

Comment: Or, alternativelly, I think it could be a nice idea, if we could create temporary tables, *or at least link other queries into our*!

Comment: There's really very little you can do in the data explorer with a temp table you can't also do with a CTE. Temp tables are to be avoided in any situation.